# Transposed convolution TensorFlow padding for FCN style networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution, image-segmentation

I am implementing some variants of FCN for Segmentation. In particular, I have implemented a U-net architecture. Within the architecture, I am applying valid convolution with a 3x3 kernel and then I apply transposed convolution for upsampling with a 2x2 kernel and stride of 2.

My question is, if using valid or same padding for the convolution, does this determine whether we use valid or same padding for the transposed convolution?

Currently I use valid padding for convolution and same padding for transposed convolution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's your decision how you calculate the kernel-map in every single convolutional layer. It's a matter of designing your model.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So my problem specifically is this, I am applying 2 by 2  transposed convolution with a stride of 2 in my U-net architecture- but I am still seeing some checkerboard like artefacts! I thought applying this filter size and stride would not result in this.

I am upsampling from an odd input. i.e my input is 25x25. Because my filter size does not fit into this exactly and I am using SAME convolution, could this be the reason for seeing these artefacts?

Comment: why not use [tf.image.resize_images](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images) with e.g. bicubic or bilinear interpolation ? In the U-Net paper it looks like they used upscaling layers, not transposed convolution layers.